# What exactly does mean the term "dereferencing" an object?

Tags: c#, dereference

I'm reading the description of the new feature in C# 8 called nullable reference types. The description discusses so called null-forgiving operator. The example in the description talks about de-referencing of an instance of a reference type (I think so):

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)

> You can also use the null-forgiving operator when you definitely know
> that an expression cannot be null but the compiler doesn't manage to
> recognize that. In the following example, if the `IsValid` method
> returns true, its argument is not null and you can safely dereference
> it:
>
> ```
> public static void Main() 
> {
>    Person? p = Find("John");
>    if (IsValid(p))
>    {
>        Console.WriteLine($"Found {p!.Name}");
>    } 
> }
> public static bool IsValid(Person? person) 
> {
>    return person != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(person.Name); 
> }
> ```
>
> Without the null-forgiving operator, the compiler generates the
> following warning for the `p.Name` code: Warning `CS8602`: Dereference of
> a possibly null reference.

I was under impression that in C# dereferencing an object means setting it to null. But it looks like Microsoft calls accessing an object's property as dereferencing the object.

The question is: what does mean the dereferencing term in C# when we are talking about a reference type instances, not about pointers managed and unmanaged.

Comment: Q:  c# dereferencing an object means setting it to null.  A: No, absolutely not.  "Dereferencing an object" means "obtain the variable pointed by a pointer": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/pointer-related-operators.  And yes, "dereferencing" applies to "reference type instances".

Comment: @paulsm4 I'd say that's as good an answer as any, you should move it to an answer to get the rep :-).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Dereferencing means following the reference to access the actual underlying object. If the reference is `null`, this causes a big problem.

Comment: Hello. What the problem can we get If the reference is null? Can you give me some links where to read about it?

Comment: @ВладимирБереза This will result in a NullReferenceException: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception?view=net-7.0

A NullReferenceException exception is thrown when you try to access a member on a type whose value is `null`.

Comment: @NielsR. Thank's. Ofcourse i know about NullReferenceException and how to prevent it. But  Joel Coehoorn said about the big problem. Maybe he meant something else in some scenarios.